# Install KNotes problem on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: system-installation

When i try to install KNotes by command "sudo apt-get install KNotes"
  It shows following 
Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading state information... Done E: Unable to locate package KNotes

Answer (score 2):

Unlike Windows, Linux commands, files, folders are **case sensistive**. So, try:

```
sudo apt-get install knotes
```